# Jmeter parameter extraction

Tags: regex, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am getting a result in my jmeter test that I don't understand:

I am trying to extract the "totalRunning" value from this Json response:

```
{"notifications":[],"taskNotificationInfo":{"totalRunning":0,"totalCompleted":0,"totalCompletedWithErrors":0,"totalFailed":0,"totalPending":0,"requestTime":1458628767436,"hasRecords":false}}
```

**My regex is configured as following:**

Reference Name: TotalRunning

Regular Expression: "totalRunning":"(.+?)"

Template: $1$

Match: 1

Default Value: 1

*screen shot:*

[image: regex extraction config]

I keep getting the default value instead of "0" in this case.
Am I extracting it from the wrong place?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expression as below:

```
Regular Expression: "totalRunning":(\d+)
```

In the question  `"totalRunning":"(.+?)"` is being used as regular expression. Since values of totalRunning is not surrounded by quotes. So none was being matched and default value is being picked.

Below regex can also be used:

```
"totalRunning":(.+?),
```

Comment: Care to share why the (.+?) didn't catch the digit? only for chars?

Comment: @TomerInbar description is shared. Have a look on that.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. I thought the (.+?) had to have the ".

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/pN6iK2/1) `totalRunning":(.+?),"totalCompleted"`

only you need to select radio button `Body` instead of `Body As a Document`
refer snapshot:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your "Field to check" to "Body" as "Body as a document" is for binary files like Word, Excel, PDF, etc. see [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article for more details. JSON is a usual text so it should be treated as "normal" response.

Also there is a special Post Processor - [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project. In case of complex JSON, multiple or conditional matches, etc. it might be better and easier to use it.

The relevant JSONPath expression will be: `$..totalRunning[0]`

[image: JSON Path Extractor]